# 2D Arrays and Null Pointer Exceptions (Java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I don't really know what's causing this problem but my program, which is supposed to be Conway's Game of Life, crashes after 2 generations, seemingly no matter what I do, and I've been trying for days to locate the error.

I've narrowed the cause down to a few possible areas--or at least, I think I have.

```
short numNeighbors(int x, int y) {
    short numNeighbors; 
    numNeighbors = 0;
    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && matrix[x][y] != null){
        if (matrix[x+1][y] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[x][y+1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[x+1][y+1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[x][y-1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[x-1][y] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[x+1][y-1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[x-1][y+1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[x-1][y-1] == true) numNeighbors++;
    }
    return numNeighbors;
}
//returns the number of neighbours that a coordinate has
```

I'm assuming that this section above checks outside of the boundaries of my 2D array, but that shouldn't be possible, because I took precautions to make sure that didn't happen. Even so, this is one possible cause.

```
void nextGen(){
    Boolean[][] newMatrix = new Boolean[rows()][cols()];

    for (int i = 1; i < cols()-1; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < rows()-1; j++){
        //avoiding null pointer errors
            if (matrix[j][i] == null) matrix[j][i] = false;
            //if a cell has 3 neighbours, become or stay true
            if (numNeighbors(j, i) == 3) newMatrix[j][i] = true;
            //if it doesn't have 3 neighbours, become or stay false
            else newMatrix[j][i] = false;
        }
    }

    matrix = newMatrix;
}
//makes matrix represent the next generation
```

This is my next guess at a cause for the error, but I can't really tell what would be wrong, though.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < numGenerations; j++){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"generation " + (j+1) + ":\n\n" + myGrid.showGrid());
        myGrid.nextGen();
    }
```

I'm only posting the above because it calls the block above it, and I don't want to rule anything out.

I don't really know what else the problem could be, but just in case anyone wants to look at the full source code of my project, I've posted it [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gUFas4EH).

Comment: what line number is the NullPointerException occuring in the stack trace? That would be a good starting point. Have you tried debugging it? Put a few break points in before the line where the NullPointerException occurs and inspect the arrays values.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace for your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nextGen you do:

```
 //avoiding null pointer errors
 if (matrix[j][i] == null) matrix[j][i] = false;
```

Do the same for all ifs in `numNeighbors()`

```
short numNeighbors(int x, int y) {
    short numNeighbors; 
    numNeighbors = 0;
    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && matrix[x][y] != null){
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && matrix[x+1][y] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && matrix[x][y+1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && [x+1][y+1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && matrix[x][y-1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && matrix[x-1][y] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && matrix[x+1][y-1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && matrix[x-1][y+1] == true) numNeighbors++;
        if (matrix[j][i] != null && matrix[x-1][y-1] == true) numNeighbors++;
    }
    return numNeighbors;
}
```

Or even better pre-instantiate all cells to false.

```
//Run in constructor
for(int i ..
   for(int j ..
      matrix[j][i] = false
```

Comment: I like the last part about pre-instantiating all cells. 1+

Comment: I just tried this and it worked, but it was with newMatrix, not matrix. I had the constructor for matrix make it false for the sake of safety, but I thought that Booleans defaulted to false in Java, but apparently they start null. I still don't know why it would work for two generations though.

Answer (score 1):

And actually, ***all*** blocks should be enclosed in curly braces. You'll save your tail many times if you take the time to do this.  e.g.,

```
if (matrix[j][i] == null) {
   newMatrix[j][i] = false;
}
```

**Edit 2**
Your big if block is going to have boundary problems. Why not simply use nested for loops:

```
short numNeighbors(int x, int y) {
  short numNeighbors; 
  numNeighbors = 0;

  int xMin = Math.max(x - 1, 0);
  int xMax = Math.min(x + 1, MAX_X - 1); // MAX_X is a constant, number of columns
  int yMin = Math.max(y - 1, 0);
  int yMax = Math.min(y + 1, MAX_Y - 1); // ditto, number of rows

  for (int i = xMin; i <= xMax; i++) {
     for (int j = yMin; j <= yMax; j++) {
        if (i != x && j != y) {
           if (matrix[i][j]) {
              numNeighbors++;
           }
        }
     }
  }

  return numNeighbors;
}
```

And as mentioned elsewhere and in my comment, the array should be initialized to non-null values so there should be no need for a null check.

Comment: That is a problem with the logic but I won't produce a NPE.

Comment: I was doing that to check for possible null values in matrix[][]. I placed similar checks around my code but they don't seem to help. I tried changing it too, and no extra information was revealed. I still get the same error, and the same crash after two generations.

Comment: My comment was directed to Hovercraft Full Of Eels pre edit answer

Comment: @Megafonzie: all items in the array should be non-null, so you shouldn't even have to do this check.

Comment: About the boundary problems, I had them accounted for already. I left a wall of coordinates around the part of the matrix I would show by just making it 2 wider and taller than it needed to be and only doing stuff to the middle. Your way's more efficient though, and I still appreciate the help!

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I think we didn't pay enough attention to the capital B while creating the Boolean array :)

Answer (score 0):

I will post another answer as I inspected your whole project.

```
void nextGen(){
    Boolean[][] newMatrix = new Boolean[rows()][cols()];
```

What you do where is creating an array of Boolean objects and not boolean primitives.

- **boolean primitives default to false**
- **Boolean objects defaults to null**

Java has something called autoboxing for primitives which can be tricky and hide this kind of "smal" differences which infact kan be realy significant as seen here,